# accessing a Chrome App from web page (from Angular)

Tags: angular, google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome app (Chrome OS) to interface with a serial port. I want to create an Angular application and access the Chrome App (as API) - from my Angular application. I am looking for any documentation that explains the interaction and setup between a Chrome App and Angular. Any help would be great. Thanks, Tom

Comment: When you say **"Chrome App"**, do you mean an app that can be installed on Chromebook? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps

Comment: Use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: Yes, I am referring to a Chromebook and a Chrome App

Answer (score 0):

[Angular](https://angular.io/guide/architecture) is a platform and framework for building single-page client applications using HTML and TypeScript. Angular is written in TypeScript. It implements core and optional functionality as a set of TypeScript libraries that you import into your apps.

Use the [chrome.serial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial) API to read from and write to a device connected to a **serial port**. Availabile: Use the chrome.serial API to read from and write to a device connected to a serial port. Availability: Since Chrome 35. **Permissions:** "serial". Learn More: Accessing ... An application-defined string to associate with the connection.ity: Since Chrome 35. Permissions: "serial". Learn More: Accessing ... An application-defined string to associate with the connection.

Comment: I was thinking of Using AngularJS for this application, but I am worried that this architecture is going away in 2022. But still this sounds like a good approach. I was looking at using Vue, but it appears to get messy.

Comment: I think you read incorrectly about it going away. AngularJS is end of life. Angular is here to stay.

Comment: @tom: if you think that Vue code is messy, you may be in for a surprise with Angular, since Vue is usually simpler to use and with a not as steep learning curve.